# Stencil Stamp not showing up

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-painting

I am trying to use texture stencil, but sometimes the stencil stamp of texture that I want to paint doesn't appear, and I can not find it. Perhaps the position of stencil stamp is elsewhere. How can I reset the position to see it again? I am using Blender 2.69.

[Blender file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_-LXTRL7Tj2Y1NFMHQ2M2N5amc/edit?usp=sharing) (go to left upper window in blender: texture draw).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Two steps would help to solve what happened in your case:

1. Set the Alpha percentage of Overlay to some non-zero-percent value;
2. Press **Reset Transform** button right behind the texture selector.

As shown below.

[image]

Btw, your texture stencil is on the upperleft corner of the 3D Viewport, which can be seen if you maximize the 3D view.

Shortcut tips when working with texture stencil and texture mask stencil:

- **For Texture Stencil:**

<kbd>RMB</kbd>: Stencil translation

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>RMB</kbd>: Stencil rotation

<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>RMB</kbd>: Stencil scale (Allow constraining on X/Y axis)

- **For Texture Mask Stencil:**

<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>RMB</kbd>: Stencil translation

<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>RMB</kbd>: Stencil rotation

<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>RMB</kbd>: Stencil scale (Allow constraining on X/Y axis)

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't realize that the alpha was zero. I cannot remember that i set it to zero. If i use RMB x or y, then the stencil image is flickering, but scaling is working. Can i avoid flickering?

Comment: I haven't met such flickering issue yet, but X/Y constraint only works with scale, currently.

Comment: +1. 'Reset Transform' seems to be the solution when [the brush stencil has been moved out of the limit of the view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzeK8.gif), and you don't remember its current position.

Answer (score 1):

Just discovered that when blender file is moved but brush textures are not, texture thumbs are still displayed on the brush reel but stencil overlay is missing. Took me a while to figure out what is going on so thought I'll share.

Answer (score 1):

If you are in version 2.8 or higher, in `Texture Paint` mode with the `Draw` tool enabled, it is necessary to activate the `Cursor` option in `Sidebar > Tool > Brush Settings > Cursor` so that the Stencil appears in the viewport when the mouse is over the model.

But don't forget that in order to use the Stencil, you must first load a texture in `Sidebar > Tool > Brush Settings > Texture` and change the `Mapping` to `Stencil`. Click the `Reset Transformation` button if necessary.

If the Stencil does not appear in `Image Paint`, make sure that the 3D Viewport is in `Texture Paint` mode.